# Nginx reverse proxy for minio presigned url throwing SignatureDoesNotMatch error

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress, minio, pre-signed-url

minio is running on url: abc.example.com:9000
For application we have xyz.example.com,
I want to reverse proxy the minio presigned URL with application url (xyzminio.example.com/presigned_url).

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name xyzminio.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://abc.example.com:9000;
    #proxy_pass_request_headers off;        
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;        
    #proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;        
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

But I'm getting below exception with 403 error code

> ```
> <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few trial and error below configuration worked:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name xyzminio.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://abc.example.com:9000;
    proxy_pass_request_headers off;
   }
  }
```